# computing upper sum of $1/x^3$ on $[-2,3]$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand upper sum of $1/x^3$ on $[-2,3]$. When I take integral of it on this interval, it does not converge. However, what is its upper sum U($1/x^3,P)$ for partition P where P={-2,0,3}. Also, is it same for any partition on this interval?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It will converge only if the upper sum and the lower sum are same. $\dfrac{1}{x^3}$ has only one point of discontinuity in $[-2,3]$. So the integral must converge.

Comment: moreover you can't take a partition in which the function is not defined at a point in it.

Comment: if f is cts at all except finitely many points and bounded then I know that f is integrable on [a,b] but here how $1/x^3$ converge since it is not bounded on [-2,3]?

Comment: also is there a valid partition on [-2,3] here like {-2,-1,3}?

Comment: there may be finite or infinite number of points of discontinuities. $1/x^3$ is of course not bounded in $[-2,3]$ but the number of discontinuities is finite.

Comment: $\{-2,-1,3\}$ is a valid partition while the previous one is not. because $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ and decreasing in $(0,3]$. To calculate $L(P,f)$ it is fair to use $\{-2,0,3\}$ but it won't give $U(P,f)$

Comment: okay thank you for your answers :)

Comment: you may calculate $lim_{\epsilon\to 0} U(p,f)$ where $P=\{-2,\epsilon,3\}$

Comment: You'll see the graph of $1/x^3$ is strictly decreasing in $1$st and $3$rd quadrant. So for $\{-2,0,3\}$, it's not possible to calculate $L(P,f)$ in $[-2,0]$ and $U(P,f)$ in $[0,3]$.